# After SourceTree update a security warning asks me to renew Mercurial

Tags: security, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree, security-warning

Since I upgraded to SourceTree 1.9.5.0, I am frequently reminded to upgrade Mercurial from 3.2.3 to 3.7.3 due to a security vulnerability. I will do that in the near future, but I am interested to know about the nature of the vulnerability.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's rather easy to find out: Look at the mercurial website. If the vulnerability is fixed in 3.7.3 it will be stated there: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_3.7.3_.282016-3-29.29

From the changelog:

> CVE-2016-3630 Mercurial: remote code execution in binary delta decoding
>
> Mercurial prior to 3.7.3 contained two bounds-checking errors in its binary delta decoder that may be exploitable via clone, push, or pull.
>
> CVE-2016-3068 Mercurial: arbitrary code execution with Git subrepos
>
> Mercurial prior to 3.7.3 allowed URLs for Git subrepos that could result in arbitrary code execution on clone. This is a further side-effect of Git CVE-2015-7545. Reported by Blake Burkhart.
>
> CVE-2016-3069 Mercurial: arbitrary code execution when converting Git repos
>
> Mercurial prior to 3.7.3 allowed arbitrary code execution when converting Git repos with hostile names. This could affect automated conversion services. Reported by Blake Burkhart.

Answer (score 11):

I'm having it too.

In SourceTree, go to *Tools* → *Options* → *Mercurial*, and just click the *Update Mercurial* button. Then restart SourceTree.

Comment: The question clearly states that the author is interested in the nature of the vulnerability, not how to update to the newer version.